# how to add label text to tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I'm practicing creating an app where I have a label that gets its text from an UITextField when the user presses a button. Now, I added another button and a tableview and I want to be able to "save" the label's text to the table cells with the same mechanism of stopwatch's laps. 
So, to be clear, I want the button to transfer the label's text to the table view cells each time I press it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your save button, you need to store the texts somewhere and reload the table. (Or insert it with animation)

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet private var tableView: UITableView!
    var texts: [String] = [] {
        didSet { tableView.reloadData() }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SimpleCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let newText = textField.text else { return }
        self.texts.append(newText)
    }
}
```

And in `tableView` dataSource methods:

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return texts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SimpleCell", for: indexPath)!
        cell.textLabel?.text = texts[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```